# Sort List of Numbers according to Custom Number Sequence

Tags: list, python-2.7, sorting

**Question :**
A set of numbers will be passed as input. Also the redefined relationship of the digits 0-9 in ascending order will be passed as input. Based on the redefined relationship, the set of numbers must be listed in ascending order.

**Input Format:**
The first line will contain the the set of numbers.
The next line will contain the digits 0-9 in the redefined ascending order.

**Boundary Conditions:**
The size of the set of numbers will be from 2 to 100.

**Output Format:**
The set of numbers in ascending order as per the redefined order of digits separated by a space.

**Example Input/Output 1:**

Input:

```
20 50 11 121
9231476058
```

Output:

```
50 11 20 121
```

Explanation:

```
121 is a three digit number and hence comes first.
As per the redefined order 2 > 1 > 5.
So 121 is greater than all others and comes in the end.
20 > 11 > 50 and hence in ascending order this is reversed.
```

**Example Input/Output 2:**

Input:

```
319 311 198 420
1948327605
```

Output:

```
319 311 420 198
```

Explanation:

```
As per the redefined order 1 > 4 > 3
Among  319 and 311, 1 > 9
Hence the final ascending order is 319 311 420 198
```

**My Solution :**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    list_ = raw_input().split()
    num = str(raw_input())
    output = sorted(list_, key = num.index)
    print(' '.join(output))
```

I need to know how to do multiple levels of sorting such that it compares indexes of first character, then second character & so on...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This matches your input/output examples, but I had to use *descending* numbers to get the example answers.  Are you sure your explanation is correct?  If not, just use `0123456789` instead of `9876543210` in the code below.

The algorithm is to provide a sorting key based on translating the digits of the number into their corresponding rank digits:

```
import string

def xsort(L,xlat):
    def xform(s):
        return int(str(s).translate(string.maketrans(xlat,'9876543210')))
    return sorted(L,key=xform)

print xsort([20,50,11,121],'9231476058')
print xsort([319,311,198,420],'1948327605')
```

Output:

```
[50, 11, 20, 121]
[319, 311, 420, 198]
```

References: [str.translate](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=translate#str.translate), [string.maketrans](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=maketrans#string.maketrans)